# Image channel error while training CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I get the following error when trying to train a CNN model:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node decode_image/DecodeImage defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Number of channels inherent in the image must be 1, 3 or 4, was 2
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1598]
```

The dataset I am working on is Cats and Dogs classification dataset from Kaggle. I defined the data like this:

```
path=r'C:\Users\berid\python\cats and dogs\PetImages'
data=tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(path)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.